# Microsoft Entity Framework Core Parent with 2 Children

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

So I have 3 classes:

```
public class OwnerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class SitterDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

public class ReviewDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public OwnerDto Owner { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("SitterId")]
    public SitterDto Sitter { get; set; }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to do the proper modelBuilder. Everything I tried fails :( I am learning so bear with me.

My closest attempt was this:

```
           modelBuilder.Entity<ReviewDto>()
                    .HasOne(t => t.Owner).WithMany().HasForeignKey("OwnerId");
```

Basically Owner and Sitter are always null :( Should i keep the [ForeignKey()] stuff or should i use a different extension method?

Comment: On the surface that looks like it should work: Inside Review, make Owner and Sitter virtual to enable lazy-loading. To retrieve an owner/sitter with a review eagerly, when selecting a Review, use a .Include(t => t.Owner) to eager-load an owner with the review. Using virtual and lazy loading will also work, but will trigger an additional call to the DB to fetch each referenced entity.  I'd recommend not using "Dto" as a naming convention for entities. DTOs / ViewModels should be POCOs that you can pass around freely rather than entities which should live in the scope of a DB context.

Comment: @StevePy sorry for the dumb question, but where should .Include(t => t.Owner) go exactly? just tacked onto the end of my HasForeignKey(..) call?

Comment: Basically I need to EF query to spit something like this out:

    select top 10 r.Id,r.Dogs,r.StartDate,r.EndDate,o.Name,s.Name
    from dbo.Review r
 join dbo.Owner o on o.Id = r.OwnerId
 join dbo.Sitter s on s.Id = r.SitterId

Comment: @StevePy eventually tried this:  var query = from a in context.Review.Include(t => t.Owner).Include(t=>t.Sitter) select a;

You're a life saver!

This is just a test project so I don't mind it not being lazy :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Declare all classes with navigation properties to each other. Mark one of the tables (the dependent table) with the `ForeignKey` attribute on its Primary Key.

EF infers one-to-many from this:

```
public class OwnerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ReviewDto> Reviewers{ get; set; }

    public ICollection<SitterDto> Sitters{ get; set; }

}

public class SitterDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public int OwnerId{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public OwnerDto Owner { get; set; }
}

public class ReviewDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }


    public int OwnerId{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public OwnerDto Owner { get; set; }

}
```

and EF infers one-to-one from this:

```
public class OwnerDto
{
    ...

    public ReviewDto Review{ get; set; }
    ...
}
public class ReviewDto
{

   [ForeignKey("Owner")]
   public int OwnerId { get; set; }
   public OwnerDto Owner{ get; set; }
   ...

}
```

Comment: but I wanted to keep my Dto's clean and a) avoid 2-way navigation and b) not expose ForeignKeys in the model itself. 

Is there a proper way to both of those?

Comment: @Steve a)It's navigation properties. you can declare 1-way navigation and b) If classes is `View Model` and you maped your data from Model into VModel so no need `ForeignKeys`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer [Eager Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading) in this scenario, You can use the `Include` method to specify related data to be includethe d in query results.

```
var query = from review in context.Review.Include(o => o.Owner).Include(s=>s.Sitter) select review;
```